# How to display <Table> tag in TextView using Html.fromHtml() method?

Tags: android, html, html-table, textview

I want to display text of `<Table>` tag in `TextView` using **`Html.fromHtml()`** method.

I've successfully displayed **`<li>`** & **`<ol>`** tags of HTML inside `TextView` using `Html.fromHtml()`.

I know that such tags are not supported by [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class in android.Though, Is there any way to display `<Table>` in `TextView` using **`Html.fromHtml()`**  or any custom **`TagHandler`**?

Comment: You are welcome to peruse the subclasses of `CharacterStyle` and see if there is a way that, between those and text, you can create a tabular structure. IMHO, you might wish to consider parsing the HTML and generating a `TableLayout` or `GridLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the suggestion. But it seems to be much more difficult to parsing the HTML text as the inline style is applied in the `<Table>`. Another way I found is to display HTML text in `WebView`, directly as it is.